# Turn summarise() output into matrices

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, dplyr, tidyverse

I was wondering what would be the shortest way to turn the output of my `summarise()` function into my 3 desired matrices?

```
z <- "group    y1    y2
1 1         2     3
2 1         3     4
3 1         5     4
4 1         2     5
5 2         4     8
6 2         5     6
7 2         6     7
8 3         7     6
9 3         8     7
10 3        10     8
11 3         9     5
12 3         7     6"

dat <- read.table(text = z, header = T)

dat %>% 
  group_by(group) %>%
  summarise(cov = cov(y1, y2) * (n() - 1),
            across(c(y1, y2), ~ var(.) * (n() - 1)))

#  group   DV1   DV2   cov
#1     1   6     2     0  
#2     2   2     2    -1  
#3     3   6.8   5.2   2.6
```

## Desired output:

```
group1 = matrix(c(6,0,0,2),2)
group2 = matrix(c(2,-1,-1,2),2)
group3 = matrix(c(6.8,2.6,2.6,5.2),2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this in a much simpler way.  After grouping by 'group', create a `list` column in `summarise` by taking the `cov` of the `matrix` created by `cbind`ing the 'y1', 'y2', and then multiply by `n() - 1`

```
out <-  dat %>% 
            group_by(group) %>%
            summarise(mat1 = list(cov(cbind(y1, y2)) * (n() - 1)), 
               .groups = 'drop')
```

-output

```
out$mat1
#[[1]]
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    6    0
#[2,]    0    2

#[[2]]
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    2   -1
#[2,]   -1    2

#[[3]]
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]  6.8  2.6
#[2,]  2.6  5.2
```

---

Or this can be done with `group_split` and `map`

```
library(purrr)
dat %>%
     group_split(group, .keep = FALSE) %>%
     map(~ cov(.x) * (nrow(.x) - 1))
```

---

In `base R`, we can use `split`

```
lapply(split(dat[c('y1', 'y2')], dat$group), 
        function(x) cov(x) * (nrow(x) - 1))
```

---

If we need to create three 'group' objects, use `list2env`

```
library(stringr)
deframe(out) %>%
     set_names(str_c('group', seq_along(.))) %>% 
     list2env(.GlobalEnv)



group1
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    6    0
#[2,]    0    2
group2
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    2   -1
#[2,]   -1    2

group3
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]  6.8  2.6
#[2,]  2.6  5.2
```

Comment: @rnorouzian If you look at the summary output in your post we have only 3 columns, but in the matrix, we want one of the diagonals to be repeated.  So, I replicated the 1st column (except the group) i.e. 'co' two times and use that in `matrix`

Comment: @rnorouzian I guess the updated simpler way would be more useful

Comment: This is great, can we also `sum()` these matricies quickly?

Comment: Do you want to sum the elements of the matrices (`purrr::map_dbl(out$mat1,sum)`) or add them to each other (`Reduce("+", out$mat1)`) ?

Comment: @rnorouzian The sum part is not clear.  Is it elementwise (as BenBolker mentioned it would be with `Reduce`) or loop over the list and do the sum as the `lapply(out$mat1, sum)`